# How can I force Firefox to render the page before it's fully loaded?

Tags: browser

As far as I know, HTML protocol allows browser to render while still fetching the entire data.

I do need to be able to read static pages before all those web fonts and other polish finish, which on my slow VPN can take forever. Suppose not using that VPN is not an option, how can I force my browser (namely Firefox) to at least show text in basic style?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Web Light](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en) transcodes (converts) web pages on the fly into a version optimized for slow clients, so that these pages load faster while saving data.

You can view the light-weight version of a desired web page by appending its URL to the googleweblight service -
http://googleweblight.com/i?u=[your_website_URL]

You can simplify the way to invoke this service by [repurposing the custom search provider feature](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2013/11/a-simpler-way-to-configure-custom.html) available in most browsers